# 4 Cucumber Reports in one Report Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, automation, cucumber, devops

I have 4 different builds in Jenkins and each of them generates a cucumber report. 
I want to combine these four reports to have one final report, but i am not finding any solution.

I would be grateful if someone can help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are looking for solution in Ruby take look at [ReportBuilder](https://github.com/rajatthareja/ReportBuilder) gem

Comment: @supputuri thank u, but project is  written in Java using Cucumber JVM + Selenium WebDriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your answers. I found the solution and i am posting it here.

The solution consisted on archiving the artifacts ( in my case .json data) for every project. You can do this in post-build section.
Than from my job where i wanted to have my final cucumber report, i just read the archived data from other projects (don't forget to tick the option Permission to copy artifact on jobs you want to collect the artifacts).
 Than in build section in final job choose option Copy artifacts from another project. 
***Important**: Don't use the same target because the data will be replaced.
Than in post build section choose cucumber report action and read in whole workspace for .json files. That's all you need to create the final report. At least for me it worked

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Allure](http://allure.qatools.ru/). It’s my first stop for any project.